# VBA - If condition met, check for value first in another sheet's range. If matching, return set value and if not then append data to new row

Tags: excel, vba, loops, range, counter

I've come pretty close to getting this working but my knowledge of VBA is limited and I'm not able to identify where/why this code fails.

Sheet1 (Destination) has a list of Case ID's and Issues in the format below:

```
Case ID      Issue 1        Issue 2      Issue 3
999          contact        email        address
998          contact
```

Sheet 2 (Data Source) has the data in the format below:

```
Case ID      Contact     Email           Address
999          Jim         jim@jim.com     123 Jim Ave
998          (blank)     (blank)         (blank)
```

GOAL: Since some Case ID's are already present in Sheet 1, the goal is to get the macro to scan through Sheet 2 and

- if the Case ID is FOUND, check to see if Issue 2 field is blank. If it is, get the column heading and paste into the same row where the Case ID is located in Sheet 1.
- if the Case ID is NOT FOUND, then append the Case ID to the last row of Sheet 1, Column A and also add the column heading to the Issue 2 column in the same row.

The goal is to highlight issues within the data sheet with multiple conditions and paste them into an "Issues" sheet. In this case, with the code below, the IF statement searches for cells that have `Interior.ColorIndex = 2` on the Data sheet (Sheet2).

PROBLEM: my current code does not cycle through correctly and append CASE ID's **not found** to the last row of Sheet 1. Also, I'm not confident my counters are setup correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub readCaseIDs()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lastrow2 As Long
Dim lastrow3 As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

Dim wb As Workbook

lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastrow3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row



For j = 2 To lastrow3
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 10).Interior.ColorIndex = 2 Then
            If Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 3) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 1) Then 
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, "D") = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 10)

            End If
        j = j + 1

            Else
                If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 10).Interior.ColorIndex = 2 Then
                lastrow2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 3).Copy
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & lastrow2 + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 10).Copy
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & lastrow2 + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                End If
            End If

    Next i
Next j

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into trading your two `For-Next` loops out for a single loop with a `.Find` function. You can also drop your `Copy-Paste` operations by setting the value directly.

```
Sub readCaseIDs()
    Dim fRng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim pasteRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook

        lastrow = .Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To lastrow

            If .Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 10).Interior.ColorIndex = 2 Then
                Set fRng = .Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Find(.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 3), , xlValues, xlWhole)

                If Not fRng Is Nothing Then
                    If .Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(fRng.Row, "D") = "" Then
                       .Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(fRng.Row, "D") = .Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 10)
                    End If
                Else
                    pasteRow = .Sheets("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    .Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & pasteRow) = .Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 3)
                    .Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & pasteRow) = .Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 10)
                End If
            End If

        Next i

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, I tried implementing this code and it doesn't seem to work. I'm getting a runtime error 91 - object variable or with block variable not set on the IF NOT FRNG is NOTHING line. any ideas?

Comment: Edited the answer.